# How to call non-observable code from rxjava chain

Tags: java, android, sqlite, rx-java

I've implemented a rxjava chain of calls in my presenter.
What it does is it calls remote server with retrofit if there are none results returned from sqlite database.

However, everything is using rxjava except our repository which calls sqlite. When the sqlite returns a result it shows me for example 3 results with null values. It seems it doesn't work to call non observable code from rxjava chain? How can I do it without using StorIO or Brite?

**Result looks like this**

[image]

**Presenter**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);

    restartableLatestCache(REQUEST_ASSIGNMENTS,
        () -> mRepository.query()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(mainThread()),
        (assignmentActivity, response) -> assignmentActivity.onSuccess(response),
        (assignmentActivity, throwable) -> assignmentActivity.onError(throwable)
    );
}
```

**Repository**

```
return mAssignmentLocalDataStore.query(new AssignmentSpecification())
            .flatMap(assignments -> assignments == null || assignments.isEmpty() ?
                    mAssignmentRemoteDataStore.query()
                        .flatMap(remoteAssignments ->
                            Observable.zip(
                                    mEntityRepository.query()
                                            .flatMap(mEntityRepository::add),
                                    mFacilityRepository.query()
                                            .flatMap(mFacilityRepository::add),
                                    mAssignmentLocalDataStore.query(new AssignmentSpecification()),
                                    (remoteEntities, remoteFacilities, assignmentsRetry) -> assignmentsRetry
                            )
                        ): Observable.just(assignments)
            );
```

**SQLite LocalDataStore**

```
@Override
public Observable<List<Assignment>> query(Specification specification) {
    final SqlSpecification sqlSpecification = (SqlSpecification) specification;

    final SQLiteDatabase database = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    final List<Assignment> assignments = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        final Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sqlSpecification.toSqlQuery(), new String[]{});

        for (int i = 0, size = cursor.getCount(); i < size; i++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);

            assignments.add(mToAssignmentMapper.map(cursor));
        }

        cursor.close();

        return Observable.just(assignments);

    } finally {
        database.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to pull the DB and check values?

Comment: Yes, I did and they are stored correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `query` to something like following (using `Observable.create`).  Another variation of this would be to return `Observable<Assignment>` and call `subscriber.onNext` for each record.

```
@Override 
public Observable<List<Assignment>> query(Specification specification) {
    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            final SqlSpecification sqlSpecification = (SqlSpecification) specification;

            final SQLiteDatabase database = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            final List<Assignment> assignments = new ArrayList<>();

            try { 
                final Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sqlSpecification.toSqlQuery(), new String[]{});

                for (int i = 0, size = cursor.getCount(); i < size; i++) {
                    cursor.moveToPosition(i);

                    assignments.add(mToAssignmentMapper.map(cursor));
                } 

                subscriber.onNext(assignments);

                cursor.close();
            } finally { 
                database.close();
                subscriber.onCompleted(); 
            } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use Observable.defer(() operator? How? :) I'll try your solution.

Comment: Works like a charm! :)

Comment: Having problems with SQLite throwing locking exceptions now but thats a new question I guess...'